# Loading different inline images for smaller screen resolutions

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to load a different inline image depending on the screen resolution (smaller resolution equals smaller image). At the minute I have this:

```
<img class="lazy" data-original="img1.jpg" src="img1.jpg" alt=""
  height="638" width="1349">
```

In the past I've used background images and media queries. Is there a way to do this using inline images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is this: **but its still a working draft and has no (broad) support yet**

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 40em)" srcset="big.jpg 1x, big-hd.jpg 2x">
  <source srcset="small.jpg 1x, small-hd.jpg 2x">
  <img src="fallback.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

More about [responsive images](http://responsiveimages.org/).

For now you might want to use the [picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) JavaScript:

```
<span data-picture data-alt="A giant stone face at The Bayon temple in Angkor Thom, Cambodia">
    <span data-src="small.jpg"></span>
    <span data-src="medium.jpg"     data-media="(min-width: 400px)"></span>
    <span data-src="large.jpg"      data-media="(min-width: 800px)"></span>
    <span data-src="extralarge.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1000px)"></span>

    <!-- Fallback content for non-JS browsers. Same img src as the initial, unqualified source element. -->
    <noscript>
        <img src="small.jpg" alt="A giant stone face at The Bayon temple in Angkor Thom, Cambodia">
    </noscript>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

fine

remove images size in **(img) tag** and set image height n width in the class="lazy" in **css file**

*and now for 2nd part image size depending on the screen resolution*

you need to use *media-query* in **css file**

for example

```
@media (min-width:320px) { .lazy{height: 200px; width: 300px;} }

@media (min-width:481px) { .lazy{height: 250px; width: 350px;} }
```

now when this image open in small-phone/devices, image size will change to 200x300

and if this image open in  tablets image size will change to 250x350

you can find more media size in internet

hope this solved your proble

have a nice day

Answer (score -2):

**@media** and **content** can be used to acheive that

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .lazy{
        content:url(" // image url ");
        }

    }
```

Works on:

Chrome 14.0.835.163
Safari 4.0.5
Opera 10.6
Does not work on:
FireFox 27.0
IE 11.0

Comment: [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gurunave/LshVM/) change the output window size to see the diffrence.